# Is it possible to capture an object in Visual Studio on a breakpoint with all values, so it can be used to create moq objects for a Unit Test?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit

In Visual Studio, if I use Copy Value, it's only the value in the Locals window, like the name of the object.  Is there a way to copy the whole object, values, lists, other objects underneath it?  I want to use it for a unit test, changing the values for my test.  I thought it would be quicker to copy and paste than having to go back and look at the object(s) and create it all by hand.

I had thought I could serialization of the object as JSON and use that to create the object in the test, but I wanted to if there are better ways.

I'm using xUnit if that matters, but it doesn't have to stay xUnit if it matters.  I'm in .NET 4.6, not Core, and it's MVC.  I do not know if any of that has a bearing.

Example:

````
public ActionResult GetEmployees(SomeObject someObject)
{
    // I want to get the someObject values from the Visual Studio IDE.  
    // someObject may be composed of other objects and lists.

}```
````

Comment: fwiw, I have used the serialization to JSON method before.

Comment: There are a couple of tools in the Marketplace.  One doesn't work.  The other claims 2019, but only installs in 2022.  I started serializing in the Immediate Window, copy the JSON, paste in test, serialize it for my mock.  Thanks for responding.